# Track bar is not working properly in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have written a program in opencv(c++) to manipulate camera property. I am trying to blur my camera display using "track bar". The code is working but in certain condition. It works, when i change the position of "track bar" using mouse click. But if i tried to slide the track bar it gives me an error as mention below.

[image]

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat image, image_blurred;
int slider=5;
float sigma=0.3 *((slider - 1)*0.5 - 1) +0.8;

void on_Trackbar(int,void *)
{
     int k_size = max(1,slider);
    //k_size = k_size%2 == 0 ? k_size+1 : k_size;
    setTrackbarPos("kernel","Blur window",3);
    sigma=0.3 *((slider - 1)*0.5 - 1) +0.8;
    GaussianBlur(image,image_blurred,Size(3,3),sigma);
}
int main()
{
    Mat img;

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"Camera is not successfully opened"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("original image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Blur Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while(!char(waitKey(30)=='q') && cap.isOpened())
    {
            cap>>img;
            GaussianBlur(img,image_blurred,Size(slider,slider),sigma);
            createTrackbar("kernel","Blur Image",&slider,21,on_Trackbar);
            imshow("Blur Image",image_blurred);
            imshow("original image",img);
    }

    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;


}
```

Please give your valuable views. Thanks in advance!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while loop, you're passing an invalid value to `GaussianBlur`, since `slider` can also be an even number.

You can correct this introducing a new variable `int kernel_size = 2*slider+1`. `slider` now is the radius of the kernel, and `kernel_size` is guaranteed to be odd.

Also you don't need to call `GaussianBlur` in the callback function, since it's already called in the main loop. The only goal of the callback is to update the values of `kernel_size` and `sigma`.

This code will work as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat image, image_blurred;
int slider = 0;
int kernel_size = 3;
float sigma = 0.3 *((kernel_size - 1)*0.5 - 1) + 0.8;

void on_Trackbar(int, void *)
{
    kernel_size = 2 * slider + 1;
    sigma = 0.3 *((kernel_size - 1)*0.5 - 1) + 0.8;
}
int main()
{
    Mat img;

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Camera is not successfully opened" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("original image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Blur Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    createTrackbar("kernel", "Blur Image", &slider, 21, on_Trackbar);

    while (!char(waitKey(30) == 'q') && cap.isOpened())
    {
        cap >> img;
        GaussianBlur(img, image_blurred, Size(kernel_size, kernel_size), sigma);
        imshow("Blur Image", image_blurred);
        imshow("original image", img);
    }

    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error E:\opencv\codes\blur_cam\main.cpp|31|error: too few arguments to function 'void on_Trackbar(int, void*)'|